# Ajax Editable label on ASP page with Masterpage

Tags: .net, html, ajax, c#-4.0

I have a ASP page with Masterpage on my web page.  On this page i will have multiple labels with an edit hyperlink next to them.  When the user clicks the Edit hyperlink i want the label to become a textbox and have the hyperlinks save and edit next to it.  I have been trying to do this and cannot get the edit hyperlink to even work when clicked on.  Here is my .js

```
/// <reference name="MicrosoftAjax.js"/>
// Global variables
var Label1, TextBox1, Edit1, Save1, Cancel1;

Sys.Application.add_init(AppInit);

function AppInit(sender) {
    Label1 = $get('labelWorkPhone');
    TextBox1 = $get('textboxWorkPhone');
    Edit1 = $get('hyperlinkEditWorkPhone');
    Save1 = $get('hyperlinkSaveWorkPhone');
    Cancel1 = $get('hyperlinkCancelWorkPhone');

    $addHandler(Edit1, "click", Edit1_Click);
    $addHandler(TextBox1, "blur", TextBox1_Blur);
    $addHandler(Save1, "click", Save1_Click);
    $addHandler(Cancel1, "click", Cancel1_Click);
}

function Edit1_Click() {
    TextBox1.value = Label1.innerHTML;

    Label1.style.display = 'none';
    TextBox1.style.display = '';

    TextBox1.focus();
}

function Save1_Click() {
    TextBox1.blur();
}

function Cancel1_Click() {
    Label1.style.display = '';
    TextBox1.style.display = 'none';
}

function TextBox1_Blur() {
    var labelUpdated;

    if (Label1.textContent == TextBox1.value)
        labelUpdated = false;
    else
        labelUpdated = true;

    Label1.innerHTML = TextBox1.value;

    TextBox1.style.display = 'none';
    Label1.style.display = '';

    if (labelUpdated)
        PageMethods.SetWorkPhone(TextBox1.value);
}
```

This is my html

```
<td class="style1">
  <asp:Label ID="labelWorkPhone" runat="server" Text="labelWorkPhone"></asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="textboxWorkPhone" runat="server" Style="display: none;"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td class="style1">
  <asp:HyperLink CssClass="a" ID="hyperlinkEditWorkPhone" runat="server" Font-Underline="True" 
    ForeColor="Blue">Edit</asp:HyperLink>
  <asp:HyperLink CssClass="a" ID="hyperlinkSaveWorkPhone" runat="server" 
  Style="display: none;">Save</asp:HyperLink>
  <asp:HyperLink CssClass="a" ID="hyperlinkCancelWorkPhone" runat="server" 
  Style="display: none;">Cancel</asp:HyperLink>
</td>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    <Scripts>
      <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/WorkPhoneJavaEdit.js" />
</Scripts>
  </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: I'm unsure about the $addHandler method, but do they methods need to be onclick and onblur?

Comment: Honestly i don't know. I was going of this article trying to do it.  I have never done ajax and just recently switched from desktop design to web design. I would guess they would have to be onclick because i need it to change when edit is clicked on.

Comment: My guess is that something is happening with the ContentHolders changing the name of controls at runtime?  Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
TextBox1.style.display = '';
```

to

```
TextBox1.style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything different